# android : Check EditText is null

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

i want to check and give condition to my edittext, if i input something to my edittext, l it will change my imageview, this is my code:

```
 if (nama_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){
            ImageView image_status=(ImageView)polis.findViewById(R.id.image_status_1);
            image_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_yellow_checklist);
        }else {
            ImageView image_status=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_status_1);
            image_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_gray_checklist);
        }
```

i have problem here, my imageview not change.... is this code has true or not?

Comment: I think you need to explain a little more clearly. What is the question?

Comment: this will work, depending on where you place this code. You would probably need a `TextWatcher`

Comment: You can use `TextUtils.isEmpty(nama_pp.getText())` to check whether the value is `null` or empty.

Comment: @codeMagic when i type something in edittext, the response i want from my ImageView is change

Comment: @AoyamaNanami Check out the answer Mike M. gave you, as it is the correct way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your post correctly, you want to check if the EditText is ever empty as the user types. If that's right, then try the following.

This line needs to appear in the onCreate method after the call to setContentView:

```
ImageView image_status=(ImageView)polis.findViewById(R.id.image_status_1);
```

Then, add this code after nama_pp has been assigned:

```
nama_pp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable p1)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        { 
            if(s.length() == 0)
            {
                image_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_yellow_checklist);
            }
            else
            {
                image_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_gray_checklist);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check your EditText is null, then you do this:

```
if (nama_pp == null)
```

But I don't think that's what you want. You want to see if the String inside is null, so you might try something like this:

```
if (nama_pp.getText().toString() == null || nama_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){
```

I think you don't need the or in this case, but I don't know if Android leaves an empty string if you delete all the characters in the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

I recently studied how to pass data among fragments and used this I like it more than other option because it easy to read and cleaner

```
if(message.text.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Message goes in here ..." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else { activity ..... whatever you wanna do
```

to deal with a user that wants to skip important data.